# Sqoop Import into hive database not happening into /user/hive/warehouse

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

I have installed **hadoop 2.7.2**, while trying to import data into hive tables using below sqoop command, why it is trying to insert into `/user/root/`  instead of inserting into `/user/hive/warehouse`

```
sqoop import-all-tables \

  --num-mappers 1 \

  --connect "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/retail_db" \

  --username=root \

  --password=root \

  --hive-import \

  --hive-overwrite \

  --hive-database sqoop_import \

  --create-hive-table
```

Answer (score 2):

Sqoop hive import will import data into HDFS first and then LOAD data into hive table.

In your case, your RDBMS table first migrated to `/user/root/<table-name>` and then loaded into Hive.

You can adjust the parent directory of the import with the `--warehouse-dir` argument. If you don't want your data to move to `/user/root/`. Use:

```
--warehouse-dir <dir>   HDFS parent for table destination
```

in your sqoop import command.

Comment: Dev thanks for the reply. It was helpful. But after running the following command I am able to see the tables from hive CLI but not from the URL in the directory /user/hive/warehouse .                                         sqoop import-all-tables \
--num-mappers 1 \
--connect "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/retail_db" \
--username=root \
--password=root \
--hive-import \
--hive-overwrite \
--create-hive-table \
--warehouse-dir /user/mydir